# How to transliterate text with emoji into UTF-8 without emoji

Tags: php, emoji, iconv, transliteration

Client gives comment in UTF-8 that may contain emoji characters. Sometimes, his keyboard automatically changes normal text into emojis.

I want to send this comment to some API that breaks with emoji.

How can I transliterate UTF-8 string to UTF-8 without emoji?

I'd like a method that would at least attempt to transliterate emoji into text, for example "" into ":P", because such emoji may have been send unintentionally, I'd like to attempt to repair previous text meaning. Thus solutions that simply remove them with preg_replace or similar are not enough.

I can't simply transliterate into ascii, as there may be UTF-8 characters of exotic languages.

Alternative solution: Is there a way how to forbid mobile keyboards from generating emoji characters?

Comment: This isn't really "transliteration", it's just text replacement: define the list of emojis you want to support, and the replacements you want to use, and do some straight-forward substitutions. Are you looking for an official list of replacements to use? A library that has some pre-defined?

Comment: On a different frame challenge: what is it that actually breaks the API? Is it that it uses old 16-bit Unicode (UCS-2, as opposed to UTF-16) internally? MySQL's broken 3-byte-only UTF-8 encoding? Some other encoding its transliterating to? Or is it just failing to _display_ the emojis? You need to know that to know which characters to replace - as far as Unicode is concerned, emojis are just one set of code points among hundreds.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, if there is such a list, I can generate replacing code myself. But without a list or library, I cannot imagine sitting down and writing such a list myself.

Comment: @IMSoP , that was my very first question to client, but he was unable to give me technicaly satisfing answer, thus I just want to replace emojis for now, as requested.